# Is it mandatory to embed Google AdSense to displays Google ads?

Tags: google-adsense

I see that on some sites Google Ads are showing up, like here:

[image]

I checked with the architect of that site and he told me that he did not embed Google AdSense on their site. So I am not sure without integrating AdSense how Google Ads are still displaying on site. Does Google automatically sense it and display without the site owners permission?

Comment: It appears you were given incorrect information. If you look at the source code, it has `https://www.google.com/adsense/search/ads.js`. So yes, you need to add [Google AdSense code](https://www.google.com/adsense/search/ads.js) on your site.

Comment: Check your browser for malware.   Occasionally rogue extensions can insert ads into the sites you visit.   The payments then go to the person controlling the extension rather than to the owner of the website.